# MSSQL schema problem - I renamed a table , now the database is referencing the old name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

here is my problem how to fix the schema of a renamed table manually.

I have a table called ActiveCustomers
I renamed it to ActiveCustomersOld
I then renamed it again ActiveCustomers ( to its original name)

Select * from ActiveCustomers it does work.
But if I rename the table to ActiveCustomerOld 
select * from ActiveCustomers works.

Why? Because SQL schema it mapping it to ActiveCustomerOld table to the name ActiveCustomers.

How do I change the schema of a table to mapp to certain keywords. 
For example
Select * from A
should map to a table called c

Comment: What happens when you do this? `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]), OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) IN ('ActiveCustomers', 'ActiveCustomersOld');`? Do you get one row or multiple?

Comment: Tagged as sql-server-2000 to prevent others from assuming 2005+ like I did. Please specify the version of SQL Server you are using when asking SQL Server questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a [`SYNONYM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) if you are using SQL Server 2005 or greater (it's always a good idea to specify the version you are using). You should also ***ALWAYS*** use the schema prefix when creating or referencing entities.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) to achieve that, though i don't know if you can mask actual entities that way.

Comment: where do i create the synonym in ssms?

Comment: In a query window. Not sure which direction you're trying to go, but for example `CREATE SYNONYM dbo.ActiveCustomers FOR dbo.ActiveCustomersOld;` (or vice-versa)

Comment: Sorry I just realized this particular server is 2003, hence no synonyms.

Comment: 2003? I think you mean 2000. Then you need to change the code to point to the right table. You could use a view in place of a synonym, but that doesn't make it a good idea.